# Average number of ratings needed to attain the given level

Tags: linear-algebra

A population can rate a product from 1 to 5 star,

So far 471 users have rated already and their average rating is 3.82 out of 5.

How many more people need to rate 5 star so that the average rating increases from 3.82 to 4.3?

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to address the following. Where did you come across this question, or what inspired you to ask it? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: **Hint:** If $n$ more people rate the product 5 stars, then the new average is 
$$
\frac{471\cdot 3.82 + 5n}{471 + n}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets mark x as the number of people needed.

$$\frac{3.82*471+5x}{471+x}=4.3$$
$$1799.22+5x=2025.3+4.3x$$
$$0.7x=226.08$$
$$x \approx 323$$

So you will need 323 people to rate 5 stars